# font awesome line chart not showing up correctly

Tags: css, font-awesome

I want to use the font awesome line chart icon in my code. I am using the      `font-awesome.css` file. The problem is I am getting a empty square/rectangle icon instead of a line graph.

JS Fiddle Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/L0uc4y2d/

Comment: Seems to work for me when you load the CSS file correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/TylerH/L0uc4y2d/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the head section of your website add this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Usually, an empty square means that the font is not loaded properly, so hopefully this will solve your problem

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fL7ezzff/4/ is a forked, and updated fiddle according to instructions in answer.

Answer (score 1):

In newer version of font awesome `faline-chart` replaced with `fa-chart-line`.
In font awesome 5 use:

```
<i class="fas fa-chart-line"></i>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css">
</head>
<body>
    Chart Line: <i class="fas fa-chart-line"></i>
</body>
</html>
```